# How to get bitly clicks (json)?

Tags: php, json, api, bit.ly

i am trying to tell the views of bit.ly link and i got the api but i dont know how to integrate it .    This is what it appears :

```
 {"status_code": 200, "data": {"units": -1, "unit_reference_ts": null, "tz_offset": -4, "unit": "day", "link_clicks": 11}, "status_txt": "OK"}
```

I am a noob at coding and tried to integrate myself,ofcourse nothing was shown on the output.
Can i have a simple php showing link_clicks number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course. It is fairly simple.

```
$json = '{"status_code": 200, "data": {"units": -1, "unit_reference_ts": null, "tz_offset": -4, "unit": "day", "link_clicks": 11}, "status_txt": "OK"}';

$object = json_decode($json);

echo $object->data->link_clicks;
```

Comment: Thank you mate,the plain tet was the output of api , but i added file_get_contents and the url of the api and it worked.
Thanks :)